# Table on paper (A4) gets cut off

Tags: pdftex, tabularx

I used tabular to create a wide table. Even-though it appears fine on pdf, when I print it on A4 the right side of the table is cut off. Any idea why this is happening? I know I can simply reduce the column width with tabular but I have no indication of the text running out of the margins until I print.

```
 \documentclass[12pt, oneside, landspace, leqno]{report}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[top=.8in, left=0.5in]{geometry}%bottom=.8in,left=1in,right=2.54cm]{geometry} % customized margins
\geometry{headsep = 25pt}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newgeometry{left=0.5cm,bottom=0.3cm,top=0.2cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[H]
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{ p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm} p{7cm}}
\toprule
Part 1&Part 2&Part 3&Part 4\\ \midrule
Bei et al., 2006 & E2 - Positive NB; PELL - classifiers SVM, NB, C4.5 & LingSpam ;PU1 & E2 94.20\% accuracy, PDB 90.10\%, PERL 88.29\% \\
Yus \& Xuin, 2005 & NB; NMN; SVM; RVM &Spam Ensemble; Babletext & SVM - 92\%, 94.5\%; NN 81.3\%, 82.7\%; NB - 93.7\%, 95.8\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{demo table}
}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document is configured for US letter paper which is wider than A4. Add `a4paper` to the class options or those for **geometry**.

Comment: Please post compilable code. As given, your code will not compile without error and does not, in any case, include the stuff which you say causes trouble and are asking for help with.  (Your tabular needs some content. You have unmatched `{`, you use an undefined float specification etc.)

Comment: `landspace` ? did you intend `landscape` ? don't put a table inside a center environment (it will not center it, just add spurious vertical space)

Comment: @cfr I resubmitted my code. Thanks for you help. David Carlisle - yeah, i believe I tried that long ago because of a wide table. I'll remove that thanks! This is my first paper with LaTeX and I've tried so many packages and snippets that I wonder how much of the packages at preamble I actually use. My preamble is crazy busy

Answer (score 3):

I guess, that you actually you like to have portrait orientation for your document and only very big table to be on landscape orientation. The table, which example you show, is not really so big that this is (to my opinion needed.

According to your preamble, you have a plan to use `tabularx` tables. With it you can already at shoved table use it in by it guarantee that it will not protrude text width on right side:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper, leqno]{report}
    \usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
    \usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}% <-- changed to usual margins
\geometry{headsep = 25pt}
    \usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash
                    \let\\\newline}X}
    \usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added for units

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lLLL}
    \toprule
Part 1  &   Part 2  &   Part 3  &   Part 4                      
    \tabularnewline\midrule
Bei et al., 2006 
        &   E2 - Positive NB; \\
            PELL - classifiers SVM, NB, C4.5
                    &   LingSpam; PU1
                                &   E2   \SI{94.20}{\%} accuracy,\\ 
                                    PDB  \SI{90.10}{\%}, \\
                                    PERL \SI{88.29}{\%}   
    \tabularnewline\addlinespace
Yus \& Xuin, 2005 
        &   NB; NMN; SVM; RVM
            &   Spam Ensemble; Babletext
                        &   SVM - \SI{92}{\%}, \SI{94.5}{\%}; \\
                            NN  - \SI{81.3}{\%}, \SI{82.7}{\%}; \\
                            NB  - \SI{93.7}{\%}, \SI{95.8}{\%} 
    \tabularnewline\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{demo table}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

IN case, that you really need wide table, than you change table orientation to lanscape. This can be done for example (also) with `rotating` package and its `sidewaystable` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper, leqno]{report}
    \usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
    \usepackage[margin=1in,show frame]{geometry}
\geometry{headsep = 25pt}
    \usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash
                    \let\\\newline}X}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{rotating}

    \begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lLLL}
    \toprule
Part 1  &   Part 2  &   Part 3  &   Part 4                      
    \tabularnewline\midrule
Bei et al., 2006 
        &   E2 - Positive NB; \\
            PELL - classifiers SVM, NB, C4.5
                    &   LingSpam; PU1
                                &   E2   \SI{94.20}{\%} accuracy,\\ 
                                    PDB  \SI{90.10}{\%}, \\
                                    PERL \SI{88.29}{\%}   
    \tabularnewline\addlinespace
Yus \& Xuin, 2005 
        &   NB; NMN; SVM; RVM
            &   Spam Ensemble; Babletext
                        &   SVM - \SI{92}{\%}, \SI{94.5}{\%}; \\
                            NN  - \SI{81.3}{\%}, \SI{82.7}{\%}; \\
                            NB  - \SI{93.7}{\%}, \SI{95.8}{\%} 
    \tabularnewline\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{demo table}
\end{sidewaystable}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

In both examples I delete in preamble of your MWE all packages which aren't related to table design. For column type I used `l` for the first column, and `L` for others. The `L` is defined in preamble.

Hopefully, this answer will give you some additional ideas, how you can design your table.

Answer (score 2):

The default layout is for US letter which does not match A4. To ensure you get A4, add `a4paper` to the class options or to the options for **geometry**. I would use:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper, landscape, leqno]{report}
```

Here, I correct the typo in `landscape` as well. Note that examining the console output when you compile sometimes tells you useful stuff such as that the 'global option' `landspace` was being ignored.

As David noted, there is no point putting a float into a `center` environment. (`table` and `figure` are examples of floats.) You probably want to use `\centering` inside the environment instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper, landscape, leqno]{report}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[top=.8in, left=0.5in]{geometry}%bottom=.8in,left=1in,right=2.54cm]{geometry} % customized margins
\geometry{headsep = 25pt}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newgeometry{left=0.5cm,bottom=0.3cm,top=0.2cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{ p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm} p{7cm}}
    \toprule
    Part 1&Part 2&Part 3&Part 4\\ \midrule
    once upon a time in biblical times the Romans were &there were a few & green apples & and crazy apes\\
    once upon a time &there were a few & green apples & and crazy apes filled the Amazonian forests\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{demo table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This does use landscape A4 but there is still something confused about your layout. You have:

\usepackage[top=.8in, left=0.5in]{geometry}%bottom=.8in,left=1in,right=2.54cm]{geometry} % customized margins
    \geometry{headsep = 25pt}
    ...
    \newgeometry{left=0.5cm,bottom=0.3cm,top=0.2cm}

but what exactly do you want? It sometimes makes sense to change the page layout after the document has started, but what would be the point of changing it before the document even begins? The original settings are (mostly, but somewhat variably and unpredictably) overwritten and only the (successful) new ones will have any effect at all.

I would also say that these are *very* small margins. I don't think any of the printers I have access to would accommodate these. The result would be that my content would be cut off when printed, even if it theoretically fitted the paper.

Here's the result as written above

[image: marginal margins]

Adding `showframe` to the options we feed **geometry**, we can see the layout:

[image: marginal margins revealed]

which is probably not what you want....

Comment: the changed the margin size at the beginning of the document because in the pdf it appeared as if the margins were too large both on the sides and top. Perhaps now that I changed the settings to a4 and return to the default margins it will look ok. The reason why I reconfigured the margins before the table was that this table has a lot of information - it comprised of citations, experiment results and looked way too busy. That was the only way I could think of to make the table look more readable.

Comment: But then do it *after* `\begin{document}` so that you can restore the original layout afterwards. Otherwise, just use those settings to start with. Or you could save the layout in the preamble, I guess, but I'd try to avoid `\newgeometry` in the preamble as I think that's not its intended use and **geometry** is somewhat... unpredictable... let's say.